# codeigniter 3 namespacing issue

Tags: php, codeigniter, namespaces, psr-4

I am working on codeigniter 3. I use composer psr-4 autoload. I enable composer config as 
`$config['composer_autoload'] = FCPATH."vendor/autoload.php";`

and my composer.json autoload as

```
"autoload":{
  "psr-4":{
      "App\\":"application"
        },
  "classmap":["system"]
  }
}
```

I have an abstract controller as `Controller.php` as

```
<?php namespace App\controllers;
use CI_Controller;
abstract class Controller extends CI_Controller{}
```

which works fine.
But The main issue is when I write as controller as

```
<?php namespace App\controllers;
use App\controllers\Controller;
use App\models\User;
class Welcome extends Controller {
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
    }
}
```

does not work. If I remove `namespace App\Controllers;` Everything goes fine.
Where is the main problem? Thank you.

Comment: try composer dump-autoload.

Comment: it does not work, I tried it before. I got `404 Page Not Found`. If I remove the `namespace App\controllers;` line the error gone.

Comment: please check what version of php you are using php >= 5.3.0 support namespaces

Comment: Yes I know that. I am using 5.6 version of php. I also note that the error come only for `namespace App\controllers;` in welcome controller. But the namespace in `Controller.php` and use statement in `welcome controller` works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter is not like Symfony, Zend, CakePHP. Its Just a basic PHP Framework which is easy to understand and use.

```
<?php 
namespace App\controllers;
use App\controllers\Controller;
use App\models\User;
class Welcome extends Controller {
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
    }
}
```

In above code you have used `namespace`, `use` keywords in code. Actually there is no requirement to load controller like that.

---

If you want add new controller. Just use like this.

File name = **`admin.php`**

```
<?php

    if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
        exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Admin extends CI_Controller {
    }
```

---

### Some Question you may get

**Is this only enough for controller??**

Yes. this code is only enough for create new controller.

**How many functions can we use inside controller**

You can use **N-Number** of functions. But as common when its more than 300 lines better to divide in to two

Comment: Yes. It is builtin with the framework. But I want to use Namespace,composer and psr-4 autoload in this framework, That was my main target. Thank you.

Comment: namespace will not work with CI. for that you have to use Symphony or some other frameworks

Answer (score 0):

You are modifying CI to use namespaces but you cannot use namespace in controller as
because of the routing process. Route will not be able to find the controller's method.